# How to upload multiple image to firebase in react native fetch blob

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, react-native

I have multiple images that are stored in an array (image paths stored in array).
then I use a for loop to upload every image, but only the last image is uploaded.
I use react native fetch blob, and firebase

```js
for(var i = 0; i < this.state.imagesUri;i++){
 Blob.build(RNFetchBlob.wrap(this.state.imagesUri[i].path),{ type : 'image/jpeg' })
            .then((blob) => firebase.storage()
            .ref("userPhoto").child("image"+i)
            .put(blob, { contentType : 'image/png' }).then(()=>{
   var storage =  firebase.storage().ref("userPhoto/").child("image"+i);
              storage.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
                var url = url;
              });
            })
          );
        }
```

Comment: this may be a really simple fix ... `for(let i = 0` instead of `for(var i = 0`

Answer (score 5):

i hope this will help

```js
 onSend(images) {
        let photo = images.map( img=> img.image); 
        photo.forEach((image, i) => {
        const sessionId = new Date().getTime();
        const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
        const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
        window.XMLHttpRequest =                     
        RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
        window.Blob = Blob;
        let uploadBlob = null;
        let mime = 'image/jpg';
        const imageRef = this.image.child(`${sessionId}${i}`);
            fs.readFile(image, 'base64')
                                .then((data) => {
                                    return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
                                })
                                .then((blob) => {
                                    uploadBlob = blob;
                                    return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
                                })
                                .then(() => {
                                    uploadBlob.close();
                                    return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
                                })
                                .then((url) => {
                                console.log(url)                                        
                               })
                                .catch((error) => {
          
                                });

                              })
                            }
```

Comment: Thank you, forEach really works well against forloop :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all, you need to cache the length of the array `this.state.imagesUri`.

This will make your for loop look like so `for(var i = 0, length = this.state.imagesUri.length; i < length;i++){`, I hope you've noticed that you aren't checking anymore if the `i < this.state.imagesUri` (This is incorrect since `imagesUri` is an array).

Comment: for(var i = 0, length = this.state.imagesUri.length; i < length;i++), can we add 4 parrameters inside for ?

Comment: Yes, just separate with a '','' `for (var i = 0, k = 0, j = 0, etc.;`

Comment: Oh and @INyomanWiratmaJaya, if you're new here, then I should let you know that if this was the answer you were looking for, you can click on the big tick below the up/down vote thingy. It helps those who come here with the same issue to know what worked to solve your issue and also helps me get some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code. To upload multi image with firebase and 'rn-fetch-blob' on react native

```
export const uploadListImageMeal = (param) => {
  const { imagesUrls, mime = 'application/octet-stream', userID, time } = param

  const urls = imagesUrls.map((uri) => {
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri
    // let uploadBlob = null
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${userID}/meal/${time}`).child(`${currentTime}.png`)
    return fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      .then((data) => {
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
      })
      .then((blob) => {
        // uploadBlob = blob
        return imageRef.put(blob._ref, blob, { contentType: mime })
      })
      .then(() => {
        // uploadBlob.close()
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
      })
      .then((url) => {
        return (url)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return host
      })
  })


  return Promise.all(urls)
    .then((data) => {
      return data
    })
}
```

Comment: You have that code, and... ? Please describe, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help future readers understand this answer